# How to enable drag sorting for specific class after adding it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, sorting, drag-and-drop

Okay, so, I have problem with my drag-n-drop sortable list.

[image: The site]

I want it to work like, when you want to edit a list item, you simply click on the item and it will turn into edit mode. The fields shows up. And now you're able to drag the item by click anywhere on the item and then just drag.

To clarify, you should not be able to drag the item from the beginning. It will just be able to do in the edit mode.

**The problem:** I am adding the class "sel" to the item with jQuery addClass, **but** the droppable function doesn't register that. So I can't use the handle ".sel > .dd-handle". And if I update the list after adding class, the class I just added disappear.

Here is the function that **adding selection** class:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.edit', function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();

    $(this).closest('li').addClass('sel');

    //update_sort();

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And here is the update_sort function that is running when the page is loaded:

```
function update_sort()
{
var tree = $(".dd-list").liveflex_treeview({
      handle        : '.sel > div.dd-handle'
    , droparea      : 'div.dd-handle'
    , opencollapse  : '.opencollapse'
    , itemMoved     : function(e)
                    {
                        var sort_array = e.serialise();

                            // Save order
                            $.post('/url_fetch/sort_posts', { 'sort_array' : sort_array }, function()
                            {
                                check_through();

                                console.log('Sparat sortering');    
                            });
                    }
});
}
```

(As you see I use liveflex, it uses jQuery's droppable and draggable functions.)

So, why doesn't the liveflex (droppable) register the addClass event? Or why won't the ".sel" class remain after update?

Comment: Anyone? Can I explain better in any way?